# CDLatex math-modify, parenthesis completion for orgmode outside of explicit environment

Tags: org-mode, latex

I would like to use CDLatex not just in specific Latex environments but anywhere. For example to quickly add emphasis or curly brackets for lesser used commands.

Currently when typing `a'e` nothing happens, but `$a'e` gets correctly expanded to `$\mathem{a}`. I would like `a'e` to be expanded to `\emph{a}` just like in auctex.

I tried setting `#+begin_export latex` but it didn't work, and showed up on the final PDF.

Comment: What about `/a/` for `\emph{a}` in "normal" text?

Comment: That would work for \emph, but there are some other wrappers like it I want to use as well.